# Convert an "8mm vintage film effect" from YouTube to a semi-transparent video (to use in Keynote)?

Tags: transparency, keynote, finalcut

I found this nice 8mm vintage film effect on YouTube:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t1Qf1rUNC7g

I read somewhere that one could simply import such a thing into e.g. Final Cut Pro and use "Screen" (or something) as blend (?) mode, so your video would have this nice effect.

But I don't own Final Cut Pro (or similar), and I especially want to use this effect in a macOS Keynote document. And while Keynote can play videos, it doesn't support any special blend modes. But it DOES support transparent (and semi-transparent) videos, so I wonder how one can convert a video like the one above in a way that dark pixels are turned into transparency?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I might be oversimplifying what you're looking to do...

If you have a Mac already you should have iMovie available to you.  You can import your "main" clip into iMovie > Clip Filter and Audio Effects > Clip Filter > Silent Era.  This adds an effect not too different than your example.  [Filter settings](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210902)

Alternatively, you could download the example file, import in to iMovie > adjust your Color Correction | White Balance settings. [Color Settings](https://support.apple.com/guide/imovie/adjust-a-clips-color-movf2a3f0f42/mac)

And I believe you know this already from your post, but you could always just download the example clip you found, import it into Keynote > Style > adjust Opacity setting to suit your need.  You can layer it on top of another video and have them play/loop at the same time to get a version of the effect you want.